# Is there a simple way to get a specific column data from the db

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a list data like this

```
var empData = this._db.empObj
                      .Where(x => x.Id == 18)
                      .OrderByDescending(x => x.Name)
                      .ToList();
```

Is there a way I can get a specific column data from the db as simple as the above? Something like:

```
string Name = this._db.empObj.Where(x => x.Id == 18)
```

Comment: var names = this._db.empObj.Where(x => x.Id == 18).Select(x=> 
 new {x.Name}).ToList()

Answer (score 2):

You can try `Single` or `SingleOrDefault`

```
var name = this._db.empObj.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 18)?.Name;
```

```
var name = this._db.empObj.Single(x => x.Id == 18).Name;
```

If you want to get a list of name

```
var names = this._db.empObj.Where(x => x.Id == 18).Select(x => x.Name);
```

Comment: _db.empObj.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 18) can return null. That's way it will throw null expection. It would be better. "this._db.empObj.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 18)?.Name;"